# Palette library changing colors while scrolling in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, palette

I've been having some problems implementing the new Palette library (on 4.4.4 with `'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'`). I am trying to color a part of each item in a GridView which works fine but when I scroll an item off the screen then back on it changes to a wrong color for a few moments before it goes back to the right color.

I thought the issue might have been calling `view.setBackgroundColor` every time getView was called, so I made a check before my code if it had already had a color generated. This made it even worse. Each time I scrolled around colors would swap With enough scrolling all my colors have swapped places. It seems like the colors are switching with each other too, not random.

Heres a snippet of what my code looks like:

```
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap,
    new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            Palette.Swatch vibrant =
                    palette.getMutedSwatch();
            if (vibrant != null) {
                fView.findViewById(R.id.colored_bar).setBackgroundColor(
                        vibrant.getRgb());
            }
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know a way to work around this problem? I heard mention of caching the response from Palette but wasn't sure if that would mean doing any more than I already am. I also tried both synchronous and asynchronous uses of Palette.
Thanks.

Comment: Post the getView() method.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think the issue might be with convertView and Palette Async functions. By the time Palette is generated for a particular bitmap, the view to which the colour should be assigned is changing and hence the colour is set to that view. Did you resolve your issue, by any chance?

Comment: Check out this post which might help you out. [Troubles with using Palette with GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188934/troubles-with-using-palette-with-gridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Basically the problem was that the palette object was created every time, which was both costly and inaccurate. Since the palette is static, I created a ViewHolder and stored the palette in that once it was created.